# Why does my for loop not go through my entire range in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a medium sized data set, with 171 columns, that I am trying to loop through. However when I run this code it runs through the first 129 columns.

```
Set Rng = Range("A1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
FirstCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight)

    Range(Range("A1"), Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Cut Sheets("ConData").Range("A1")

    For Each cell In Rng
        Range(Range("A1").End(xlToRight), Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Select
        NumRow = Selection.Rows.Count
        Selection.Resize(NumRow, 3).Cut Sheets("ConData").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        Next
```

Here is an example of the data set I am working with:

[image: Data]

I am still learning, so if somebody could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your code attempting to do? It looks to me like it's cutting/blanking columns. I feel there might be an easier way of doing it. The first line in your "FOR EACH" will only select up until there is a blank row / gap in data in the column. That could be why it's stopping at 129.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I have updated my question with a picture of the data. I am attempting take all data on one sheet, and cut/paste to separate sheet, in order to have all data in 3 columns. I can also confirm there are no blanks in the data.

Comment: The data in the image goes from column A to S.  You want to cut _all_ data and paste in columns A to C.  How do you condense columns A to S into A to C or do you want to just cut columns A to C into the second sheet?

Comment: Do you mean "have all the data in 3 sheets"? If so, why not just copy the sheet twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```vb
Sub Reorg()
    
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 3
    Dim rngHdr As Range, rngCopy As Range, rngDest As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set rngHdr = ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, NUM_COLS) 'first set of headers
    Set rngDest = ws.Parent.Worksheets("ConData").Range("A1") 'first paste location
    
    Do While Application.CountA(rngHdr) > 0 'while have headers
        
        Set rngCopy = ws.Range(rngHdr(1).Offset(1), _
           ws.Cells(Rows.Count, rngHdr(1).Column).End(xlUp)).Resize(, NUM_COLS)
           
        rngCopy.Copy rngDest 'or .Cut
        
        Set rngHdr = rngHdr.Offset(, NUM_COLS) 'offset to the right
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(rngCopy.Rows.Count) 'offset down
    
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Is it possible to alter the rngCopy range from counting the rows in Column A, to counting the columns for the current select in each loop? e:g count rows in Column A in the First instance, then Column D on the next loop, then G etc.

Comment: You mean your blocks of 3 columns are different lengths?

Comment: See edit above.